# Quantos dias faltam para uma data

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Alguém tem uma consulta no sql server que retorna quantos dias faltam para uma data?
Tenho a data de admissão do funcionário, preciso saber, quantos dias faltam para completar 45 dias e quantos dias faltam para completar 90 dias.

Comment: Quantos dias faltam para completar 45 dias ??? um pouco confuso isso , poderia especificar melhor sua pergunta e e qual banco você esta usando.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza tenho a data de admissão do funcionário, a partir daí quero saber quantos dias faltam para ele completar 45 dias de trabalho, e depois quantos dias faltam para completar 90 dias e quando faltar 5 dias para 45 vou disparar email notificando e consequentemente irei fazer isso quando estiver faltando 5 dias para completar 90 dias, entendeu melhor agora? Aqui utilizo SQL Server

Comment: conseguiu resolver seu problema ?

Comment: Consegui, usei seu exemplo mesmo, de colocar 45 - datediff, deu certo, obrigado, como faço para colocar o post como resolvido?

Comment: só você marcar como aceita a resposta .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) e combine sua data com o [GETDATE()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) que pega a data atual, depois disso use alguma lógica para envia seu email.

```
declare @DtInclusao Datetime = '16/07/2017'    

-- Dias transcorridos
SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY, @DtInclusao , GETDATE())

-- Dias que faltam  para 45 dias
SELECT 45 - DATEDIFF (DAY, @DtInclusao , GETDATE())

-- Dias que faltam  para 90 dias
SELECT 90 - DATEDIFF (DAY, @DtInclusao , GETDATE())


if DATEDIFF ( DAY , @DtInclusao , GETDATE()) = 5
  print 'enviar email'
```

Conforme mencionado nos comentários;

```
declare @funcionarios table
(   
    Nome varchar(100),
    DtInclusao Datetime 
)   

insert into @funcionarios values ('João', '01/06/2017') 
insert into @funcionarios values ('Maria', '05/06/2017') 
insert into @funcionarios values ('Paulo', '21/06/2017') 
insert into @funcionarios values ('Andre', '01/07/2017') 
insert into @funcionarios values ('Carlos', '11/07/2017') 

-- Dias transcorridos
SELECT nome, DATEDIFF (DAY, DtInclusao , GETDATE()) as DiasTranscorridos ,
(45 - DATEDIFF (DAY, DtInclusao , GETDATE())) as DiasP45,
(90 - DATEDIFF (DAY, DtInclusao , GETDATE())) as  DiasP90
from @funcionarios
```

Comment: Entendi o que vc fez , mas eu tenho uns 10 funcionários e eles tem data de admissão diferentes, como vou retornar os dias que faltam para completar os 45 e 90 dias?

Comment: No lugar do @DtInclusao use o campo da sua tabela

Answer (score 6):

Caso esteja utilizando o SQL Server, utilize o DATEDIFF

Exemplos:

diferença do dia : `SELECT DATEDIFF ( DAY , '21/07/2017' , '30/07/2017' )`

diferença do mês: `SELECT DATEDIFF ( MONTH , '21/07/2017' , '21/09/2017' )`

diferença do ano : `SELECT DATEDIFF ( YEAR , '21/07/2015' , '21/07/2018' )`

Para a sua necessidade :

```
Declare @DataAdminissao datetime
     set @DataAdminissao = '20/06/2017'

SELECT DATEDIFF ( DAY , getdate() , @DataAdminissao + 45 )
```

O retorno desse exemplo vai ser 14, quando chegar no 5 ou 3 dia, você pode colocar uma proc para disparar um e-mail de alerta.

Comment: Ricardo, entendi sua resposta, mas estou querendo saber quantos dias faltam para chegar numa data, e não a diferença de dias entre elas.

Comment: certo, no primeiro campo de data utilize o GETDATE(), que é a data atual do sistema, e no ultimo coloque a data que deseja... ai sim você terá o retorno que precisa. Faça o teste.

Comment: tenho a data de admissão do funcionário, a partir daí quero saber quantos dias faltam para ele completar 45 dias de trabalho, e depois quantos dias faltam para completar 90 dias e quando faltar 5 dias para 45 vou disparar email notificando e consequentemente irei fazer isso quando estiver faltando 5 dias para completar 90 dias, entendeu melhor agora? Aqui utilizo SQL Server

Comment: @MarcilioEloi acabei de editar a minha resposta e colocar mais um exemplo. Creio que isso já te atenda.

Comment: Entendi, mas vc setou uma data, eu tenho vários funcionários com data de admissão diferentes.

Answer (score 5):

Exemplo com Oracle:

```
select to_date('2017-07-21','YYYY-MM-DD') - to_date('2017-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
from dual;
```